# How to iterate through a dictionary without skipping entries with duplicate keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

The code:

```
params = {'shift' : 'day',
                'item_served': 'enchiladas',
                'item_served': 'sushi',
                'item_served': 'polenta'}

for key, value in params.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Currently outputs:

```
shift
day
item_served
polenta
```

But this is what I'm looking for:

```
shift
day
item_served
enchiladas
item_served
sushi
item_served
polenta
```

How do you modify the code so that the entries with duplicate keys but different values are not overwritten?

Comment: The iteration isn't the problem. The dictionary doesn't have duplicate keys because dictionaries don't support duplicate keys.

Comment: use `defaultdict` instead of dictionary.like `{'item_served': ['aa', 'bb']}
`